# MongoDB: Retrieving only specific record

Tags: java, sql, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm new to Mongo, and I'm trying to retrieve specific data among several with same name from a find() query:

Let me explain->
Users is collection with following document:

```
"linkedaccounts": [
  {
    "accountname": "Rani Charan",
    "accountnumber": "10815748690065",
    "ifsc": "UTIB0001081",
    "virtualid": "taran@xyz",
    "_id": "571488b9720023940539959e",
    "isDefaultReceiving": false,
    "isDefaultFunding": false,
    "isAppEnabled": false,
    "aeba": false,
    "accountsource": 0
  },
  {
    "accountname": "Rani Singh",
    "accountnumber": "01316366360080",
    "virtualid": "ranisingh@xyz",
    "_id": "571488b972002394053995a0",
    "ifsc": "UTIB0000131",
    "isDefaultReceiving": false,
    "isDefaultFunding": true,
    "isAppEnabled": true,
    "aeba": false,
    "accountsource": 0
  },
  {
    "accountname": "Rani K Singh",
    "accountnumber": "07916956560873",
    "virtualid": "ranik@xyz",
    "_id": "571488b9720023940539959f",
    "ifsc": "UTIB0000791",
    "isDefaultReceiving": true,
    "isDefaultFunding": false,
    "isAppEnabled": true,
    "aeba": false,
    "accountsource": 0
  }
]
```

now i want to fetch account number and ifsc code where virtual id is "ranisingh@xyz" . i able to get some filtered data using this query:

```
db.users.find(
         {"linkedaccounts.virtualid": "ranik@xyz"}, 
         {_id: 0, 'linkedaccounts.accountnumber': 1,'linkedaccounts.ifsc': 1})
```

but in result i get all three accountsnumber and ifsc code . like this:-

```
{
    "linkedaccounts" : [
            {
                    "accountnumber" : "10815748690065",
                    "ifsc" : "UTIB0001081"
            },
            {
                    "accountnumber" : "01316366360080",
                    "ifsc" : "UTIB0000131"
            },
            {
                    "accountnumber" : "07916956560873",
                    "ifsc" : "UTIB0000791"
            }
    ]}
```

so now i want to print only one accountnumber and ifsc code that beleongs "ranisingh@xyz".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use $slice to get first element from an array:

```
 db.users.find(
  {"linkedaccounts.virtualid": "ranik@xyz"} ,
  {
    _id: 0,     
   linkedaccounts: {$elemMatch: {virtualid:"ranik@xyz"}}
   }
);
```

but to reshape document you need to use aggregation like this:

```
   db.users.aggregate([
   {$unwind:"$linkedaccounts"},
   {$match:{"linkedaccounts.virtualid":"ranik@xyz"}},
   {$project:{
       _id:0,
       linkedaccounts:
            {accountnumber:"$linkedaccounts.accountnumber",
                      ifsc:"$linkedaccounts.ifsc"}       
       }}
   ])
```

Comment: No effect , same result sir.  @profesor79

Comment: @SunnyDhiman hi - thx for feedback - just realized that there were extra {} - now fixed

Comment: @profesor79 I don't think this will help - we don't want the first item in the array, we want whichever item matches the query condition.

Comment: the OP ask only ONE and there is no other specs for that

Comment: hi @profesor79 thnks for query-  but it always provide first accountnumber and ifsc ,my requirement is i want to get data according to virtual id which i provide in " " like ranisingh@xyz.

Comment: @SunnyDhiman - yes - |I overlooked this requirement and even sad that there was no such requirement - apologies for that! fixed now.

Comment: @profesor79 this query printed whole array , i want just accountnumber and ifsc code . that matches virtual id.

Comment: @SunnyDhiman thee is aggregation example

Comment: @profesor79 Thanks a lot , this is what exactly i need... thanks once again..!!!!

Answer (score -2):

You can use the "positional $ operator" to make it return only the matching sub-document, instead of all sub-documents in the array. Try this:

```
db.users.find(
  {"linkedaccounts.virtualid": "ranik@xyz"} ,
  {
    _id: 0, 
    'linkedaccounts.$.accountnumber': 1,
    'linkedaccounts.$.ifsc': 1
   }
);
```

That should return you only the matching sub-document, like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("564b16849408a50b00ec235e"),
  "linkedaccounts" : [
    {
      "accountnumber" : "07916956560873",
      "ifsc" : "UTIB0000791"
    }
  ]
}
```

Ref: [https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj.*S*](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_)

Update in reply to comments: this does not work, because this type of query is limited to only one use of the positional $ operator. I recommend using the aggregation pipeline instead.

Comment: "errmsg" : "Cannot specify more than one positional proj. per query.",

Comment: Ah yes, that is a limitation. I think you might need to use the greater power of the aggregation pipeline instead to get exactly what you are after.

Comment: there is no need for aggregation - my query is sufficient ;-) - pls try it

Comment: hi vincebowdren there is error:   Error: error: {
        "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Positional projection 'linkedaccount.$.accountnumber' does n
ot match the query document.",
        "code" : 2

Comment: @SunnyDhiman - this answer will not work; as professor79 has mentioned, this type of projection has a limitation that you cannot use more than one positional projector per query. But I think the error you are getting is due to a typo: "linkedaccount" instead of "linkedaccounts".

Comment: @vincebowdren now i using only one positional projector as you mention to get only accountnumber but in result whole linkedaccount array printed.

Comment: Query:    db.users.find(
  {"linkedaccounts.virtualid": "ranik@xyz"} ,
  {
    _id: 0, 
    'linkedaccounts.$.accountnumber': 1
   }
)

Comment: @vincebowdren result:  "linkedaccounts" : [
                {
                        "accountname" : "Rani K Singh",
                        "accountnumber" : "07916956560873",
                        "virtualid" : "ranik@handypay",
                        "_id" : "571488b9720023940539959f",
                        "ifsc" : "UTIB0000791",
                        "isDefaultReceiving" : true,
                        "isDefaultFunding" : false,
                        "isAppEnabled" : true,
                        "aeba" : false,
                        "accountsource" : 0
                }
   ]

Comment: @SunnyDhiman Sorry, it won't work: I was wrong about how much use you could get out of the positional $ operator.